# Operador logico deixando de funcionar?

Tags: java

Olá estou fazendo um projeto em java que envolve pilhas e filas, no entanto ate ai tudo bem, porem entre alguns condicionais que eu fiz com if um deles "apresentou" um erro (Na verdade não apresentar ou fazer oque ele deveria fazer é o "erro" em questão...

Segue a baixo o código fonte

```
     try
 {  
    String equa = txtEqua.getText();
    StringTokenizer quebratuto = new StringTokenizer(equa,"+-*/^()",true);
    Pilha p = new Pilha(quebratuto.countTokens());
    Fila f = new Fila(quebratuto.countTokens());
     TabelaDePrecedencias table = new TabelaDePrecedencias();
        while (quebratuto.hasMoreTokens())
        {       
           String token = quebratuto.nextToken();
            char topo = ' ';
            char sequencia = ' ';
            try
            {
                Double nro = Double.parseDouble(token);
                f.guardeUmItem(nro);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException erro)
            {
                if (token == "(")  //não está entrando neste cara aqui :/
                {
                    p.guardeUmItem(token);
                    continue;
                }

                if(p.vazia())
                {
                    p.guardeUmItem(token);
                    continue;
                }


                    sequencia = token.charAt(0);
                    teste2.setText(sequencia+"Sequencia");
                    topo = (char)p.getUmItem();
                    teste3.setText((char)topo+"Topo");


                Boolean devoDesenpi = table.devoDesempilhar(topo,sequencia);
                if(devoDesenpi==true && sequencia == ')')
                {
                   teste2.setText(devoDesenpi.toString());
                  char salvaItem = (char)p.getUmItem();
                  while (salvaItem != '(')
                  {
                    p.jogueUmItemFora();
                    f.guardeUmItem(salvaItem);
                    salvaItem = ' ';
                  }
                   if(salvaItem == '(' || salvaItem == ')')
                       p.jogueUmItemFora();
                }
            }
       }
 }
 catch(Exception erro)
 {     
     teste2.setText("Ta errado :/");
 }
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece? em que momento? tente ser mais explicativo e coloque tudo que tiver de código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparação de strings em Java é feita com o método `equals()`.

```
if (token.equals("(")) {
   ...
}
```

Ou então compare o caracter individual, que é de tipo numérico e pode ser comparado com `==`, como por exemplo `if (token.charAt(0) == '(') {`